# Convert multiple FBX to glTF using FBX2glTF

Tags: powershell, fbx, gltf

Referencing this site:
https://help.plattar.com/en/articles/1667498-converting-fbx-to-gltf-using-fbx2gltf

I'm able to export a single FBX file to glTF using the following command in powershell:

```
.\FBX2glTF-windows-x64.exe '.\fbxname.fbx'
```

This is with the FBX2glTF executable sitting in the same folder as the FBX.

How can I go about looping through multiple FBX files in the folder and create multiple glTF output for each?

I have tried the following code, however it seems to only print out the command as a string:

```
$files = @(Get-ChildItem "file_path_to_fbx\*.fbx")
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $output = ".\FBX2glTF-windows-x64.exe" + " .\" + $file.basename
    $output 
}
```

Comment: What have you got so far? We won't write code for you from scratch. From what I can see, you should be looking into `get-childitem` and looping.

Comment: Question updated to include my attempt at looping through the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting your $output variable, you are declaring everything as a string. You should be able to call it the same way you were when executing it for a single file. Something like this:

```
$files = @(Get-ChildItem "file_path_to_fbx\*.fbx")
foreach ($file in $files) {
    .\FBX2glTF-windows-x64.exe  "$($file.fullname)"
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This did the trick, I just needed to change the last bit to ".\$($file.Name)" and it's running perfectly.
Thanks for the help!